# Constrained optimization of $f(x,y) = e^{-x^{2}-y} $

Tags: calculus, optimization

> Let $f(x,y) = e^{-x^{2}-y} $ and the constraint set $M$ be $\{(x,y): y^2 = e^{-x^2}\}$. Then
>
> A. $f(x,y)$ is not bounded on $M$
>
> B. $(0, -1)$ is point of local mimimum
>
> C. $(0,1)$ is point of local maximum.

I simply substituted the constaint into the function, i.e.

$$f(x,y) = e^{-x^{2}-y} = y^2 e^{-y}  $$

FOC: $$2y e^{-y} - y^2 e^{-y} = 0$$

The critical points are $\{0,2\}$. Hence, B,C are false.

A is true because $\lim_{y \rightarrow - \infty} y^2 e^{-y} = \infty$.

The problem is that the answer is supposed to C. Could you please help me to understand where I made a mistake.

Comment: May be the second derivative test could help.

Comment: How? y must be either 0, or 2, not 1 or -1.

Comment: Yes; try with $y=0$ and $y=2$ which are the places where the first derivative wrt $y$ is zero. I don't think I ever spoke about $\pm 1$.

Comment: But why? Please have a look at choices. None of them contains 0 or 2 as y.

Comment: A cannot possibly be correct. You say to examine $y \to - \infty$, but how can that occur if $f$ is restricted to the constraint set $M = \{(x,y): y^2 = e^{-x^2}\}$? On $M$, $y$ is bounded by the maximum of $e^{-x^2}$, which occurs at $x = 0$. That is, your $y$ values are bounded by $|y| \leq 1$.

Comment: No, I didn't make a misprint. Sorry. Thank you for A.

Comment: @AvaSkovko I posted an answer that hopefully addresses your question (particularly, about the critical points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimizing $f(x,y) = e^{-x^2 - y}$ on the curve $M : y^2 = e^{-x^2}$, we find that 
$$
f(x,y) = e^{-x^2 - y} = y^2 e^{-y}
. 
$$
Then, $0 = f'(y) = 2y e^{-y} - y^2 e^{-y} = ye^{-y} (2 - y)$, so that $y = 0 , 2$. However, we see that $y=0$ does not lie on $M$, and $y = 2$ corresponds to $x = \sqrt{ - \ln 4 }$, which is imaginary (that is, a non-real coefficient). Hence, neither of these possible critical values for $f$ will work, as they do not correspond to points on the constraint curve $M$!!! (not factorial - *emphasis*)

So, we must approach this a little differently - what if we know try to write $f$ as a function of $x$? Well, then we consider the function on the two different paths parametrizing $M$: $f_+$ where $y = (+) \sqrt{e^{-x^2}}$ and $f_{-}$ where $y = (-) \sqrt{e^{-x^2}}$.
$$
f_+ (x) = e^{-x^2 - \sqrt{e^{-x^2}}} , \quad f_- (x) = e^{-x^2 + \sqrt{e^{-x^2}}} .
$$
Now, $f_+ ' (x) = 0 \implies (-2x - \frac{1}{2} \frac{-2x e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{e^{-x^2}} }) f_+ (x) = 0$, that is, as $|f(x)| > 0$, we must have that $0 = x(\sqrt{e^{-x^2}} -2)$, or $x = 0 ,\sqrt{-\ln 4}$ (and we know which of those we can throw out right away!!!). Note that we can check $f_{-} '( x) = 0$ as well, to find that $0 = -x(2 + \sqrt{e^{-x^2}})$ so that $x = 0 $. Now, we just check that $x=0$ corresponds to a point(s) on the constraint $M$, which it does - the points $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$. Now, we just check which of these corresponds to local extrema (and which kind). As we know it must be $B$ or $C$, we can check rather easily which is correct.

Comment: For determining what kind of extrema occur at the critical points, think about what is happening locally to the function on the set $M$.

Comment: Thank you for you help. To be honest, I expected some trick that makes the problem very simple. It looks like I was expected to know how that contraint looks like. Do you know, does this curve have a name? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%5E2+%3D+exp%28-x%5E2%29

Comment: @AvaSkovko If it does, I am not aware of it (a name) - it is a little similar to a kind of "stretched" Gaussian curve ($y = e^{-x^2}$), which is a common curve (and there is a reflected component as well from $y^2$ admitting $\pm y$ curves, which I mention in the post). It generally helps to know what the constraint looks like, even just for visualizing. As for simplifying the problem - honestly, it seems very simple. I can list the steps: 1. Use constraint to turn $f$ into a single variable function. 2. Find critical points, and check they are on the constraint. 3. Check extrema (types).